# MySql Pivot table based on Count of Transactions

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, pivot-table, aggregate

I have been asked to create a report that displays transaction data for individual members and shows how often they have made the same type of transaction.

For example:

> Bob from organization X has purchased 5 bananas at once on 10
>   different occasions/transactions and Bob from that same organization
>   has purchased 3 bananas at once on 20 different
>   occasions/transactions.

The database contains transaction data in this form

```
|TransactionID | Organization | MemberNumber | ItemID| QuantityPurchased
```

I currently have a query that creates a temp table in the following format.

```
|Organization | MemberNumber | ItemID | QuantityItemsPurchased | QuantityOfTransactions
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Company X    | 2044         | B2     | 5                      | 10
|Company X    | 2044         | B2     | 3                      | 20
|Company Y    | 2035         | A3     | 5                      | 5
```

I have been asked to create a report in the following format (The format of the report is not up for me to debate), where each number column is transactions with that quantity of items sold and the value in each row is the number of transactions that sold that quantity of items.

```
|Organization | MemberNumber | ItemID |1  |2  |3  |4  |5  |6+ |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|Company X    | 2044         | B2     |0  |0  |20 |0  |10 |0  |
|Company Y    | 2035         | A3     |0  |0  |0  |0  |5  |0  |
```

I am not sure how to write a query that can sort **quantityOfItemsPurchased** into individual columns and display the **QuantityOfTransactions** value.

I tried writing a query similar to below, but it  is not working for me as it just gives a value of 1 or 0 under all the number columns instead of the actual **QuantityOfTransactions** value.

```
Select Organization, MemberNumber, ItemId,
count(Case when tempTable.quantityOfItemsPurchased = 1 then tempTable.QuantityOfTransactions  end) as '1',
count(Case when tempTable.quantityOfItemsPurchased = 2 then tempTable.QuantityOfTransactions  end) as '2',
count(Case when tempTable.quantityOfItemsPurchased = 3 then tempTable.QuantityOfTransactions  end) as '3',
count(Case when tempTable.quantityOfItemsPurchased = 4 then tempTable.QuantityOfTransactions  end) as '4',
count(Case when tempTable.quantityOfItemsPurchased = 5 then tempTable.QuantityOfTransactions  end) as '5',
count(Case when tempTable.quantityOfItemsPurchased >= 6 then tempTable.QuantityOfTransactions  end) as '6+'
from TempTable group by Organization, MemberNumber, ItemId
```

Comment: This kind of thing is so easy in application code. :-(

Comment: Strawberry, agree that it would be easier, but we are trying to keep these kinds of reports separate from the application as sales/management is always asking for modifications to reports and its not practical to have to constantly publish a new build every time that happens. Unfortunately my DB knowledge is limited, but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
SELECT Organization, MemberNumber, ItemID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN QuantityItemsPurchased = 1 
           THEN QuantityOfTransactions ELSE 0 END) As `1`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN QuantityItemsPurchased = 2 
           THEN QuantityOfTransactions ELSE 0 END) As `2`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN QuantityItemsPurchased = 3 
           THEN QuantityOfTransactions ELSE 0 END) As `3`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN QuantityItemsPurchased = 4 
           THEN QuantityOfTransactions ELSE 0 END) As `4`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN QuantityItemsPurchased = 5 
           THEN QuantityOfTransactions ELSE 0 END) As `5`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN QuantityItemsPurchased >= 6 
           THEN QuantityOfTransactions ELSE 0 END) As `6+`
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Organization, MemberNumber, ItemID
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da1427/18)

Comment: krokodilko,

This seems close but its the opposite of what I am trying to do. Please see last table in my question to see what the final results should look like. 

Your answer is switching the quantityItemsPurchased and the quantityOfTransactions. I'm trying to work with the example you provided to see if I can come up with something that works.

Comment: krokodilko, switching the columnnames in the query seemed to do the trick, see. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da1427/18